# How can I host qwik framework on github pages?

Tags: github-pages, vite, qwik

I've tried to use the documentation [here](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/advanced/custom-build-dir/) and [here](https://qwik.builder.io/qwikcity/static-site-generation/static-site-config/#ssg-config) in order to generate static files and put them into the docs folder, but for some reason, the site looks broken. The splitted JS files don't work as they should when using the auto-generated GitHub URL `https://github.com/<UserID>/<RepoName>`. So, I ended up using a subdomain of my own and having the errors which are posted at the of this post.

My vite.config.ts

```
import { qwikCity } from "@builder.io/qwik-city/vite";
import { qwikVite } from "@builder.io/qwik/optimizer";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    ssr: { target: "node", format: "cjs" },
    plugins: [
      qwikCity(),
      qwikVite({
        client: {
          outDir: "docs/",
        },
      }),
      tsconfigPaths(),
    ],
  };
});
```

My entry.static.tsx

```
import { qwikCityGenerate } from '@builder.io/qwik-city/static/node';
import { join } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import render from './entry.ssr';

// Execute Qwik City Static Site Generator
qwikCityGenerate(render, {
  origin: 'https://qwik.builder.io/',
  outDir: join(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url), '..', '..', 'docs'),
});
```

And my package.json

```
 "name": "my-qwik-basic-starter",
  "description": "Recommended for your first Qwik app (comes with Qwik City)",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=15.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "qwik build",
    "build.client": "vite build",
    "build.full": "npm run build && npm run build.static && node server/entry.static.js",
    "build.preview": "vite build --ssr src/entry.preview.tsx",
    "build.static": "vite build --ssr src/entry.static.tsx",
    "build.types": "tsc --incremental --noEmit",
    "dev": "vite --mode ssr",
    "dev.debug": "node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js --mode ssr --force",
    "fmt": "prettier --write .",
    "fmt.check": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts*\"",
    "preview": "qwik build preview && vite preview --open",
    "ssg": "node server/entry.static",
    "start": "vite --open --mode ssr",
    "qwik": "qwik"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@builder.io/qwik": "0.10.0",
    "@builder.io/qwik-city": "0.0.112",
    "@types/eslint": "8.4.6",
    "@types/node": "latest",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.40.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.40.0",
    "eslint": "8.25.0",
    "eslint-plugin-qwik": "0.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "3.2.10",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
    "vite": "3.1.7",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "3.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.12.0",
    "minimasonry": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Trying to run `npm run build.full`

Getting those errors in the console

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_qc_')
    at ee (q-9c2a9820.js:2:28350)
    at S (q-9c2a9820.js:2:28367)
    at q-9c2a9820.js:2:27830
    at Or (q-9c2a9820.js:2:28337)
    at Us (q-9c2a9820.js:2:17115)
    at Vs (q-9c2a9820.js:2:17549)
    at c ((index):8:2636)

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Dt')
    at Vs (q-9c2a9820.js:2:17567)
    at c ((index):8:2636)
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With `"@builder.io/qwik": "0.11.0"` & `"@builder.io/qwik-city": "0.0.112"`

and running `"build.full": "npm run build && npm run build.ssg && npm run ssg"`

`run build.ssg` beeing `"build.ssg": "vite build --ssr src/entry.static.tsx"`

I was able to deploy on Github Pages [this repo](https://github.com/JeanMeche/qwik-app), [here](https://jeanmeche.github.io/qwik-app/). Using this deploy script :

```
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    steps:
      - name: Setup Node.js for use with actions
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.5.0

      - name: Clean install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build app
        run: npm run build && npm run build.ssg && npm run ssg

      - name: deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./dist
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I do think this framework is still at its beginning and not ready enough for use cases like GitHub pages for example.

Comment: @TamirGilany The CSS issue has been fixed with 0.13 !

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to do as you did and also fixed my build scripts and updated all the packages but no luck. Still having some issues. I also see that you have errors in your console ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Currently well need for [#2462](https://github.com/BuilderIO/qwik/issues/2462) to be fixed for it to work correctly !

Answer (score 0):

To host on Github Page, you'll have to publish your project in static HTML. To do that in Qwik, you'll run

```
npm run qwik add
```

Select Adapter: Static site (.html files). Done!

You can [read more about SSG here](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/guides/static-site-generation/)

Comment: Thanks, if anyone can verify it works please leave a comment (ditched my project for now)

Answer (score 0):

I finally could successfully deploy to GitHub Pages but there's still issues that need to be fixed. I don't really know if they already are but I did let them know here [Qwik Issues](https://github.com/BuilderIO/qwik/issues/3653#issuecomment-1555344546). What I did was copy all error's path from console and add them to my DocumentHead with repo's name.

I'm using Qwik v0.105.0

https://da8ah.github.io/qwik-digency-home/

Logs from the console in dev tools (right-bottom)

[Website with dev tools open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJYQ3.png)

[Root component](https://github.com/da8ah/qwik-digency-home/blob/main/src/root.tsx)

```
export const subpath = "/qwik-digency-home";
<link rel="manifest" href={`${subpath}/manifest.json`} />
```

[Router head](https://github.com/da8ah/qwik-digency-home/blob/main/src/components/router-head/router-head.tsx)

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href={`${subpath}/favicon.svg`} />
<link rel="stylesheet" href={`${subpath}/build/q-1c3cd476.css`} />
```

I used this [Qwik SSG](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/guides/static-site-generation/#static-site-generation-config) and [GitHub Pages Static Deploy](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages) to:

- Generate Static Site (build)
- Config GitHub Pages Actions with the deploy script

This files must be config for the build:

vite.config.tsx

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { qwikVite } from "@builder.io/qwik/optimizer";
import { qwikCity } from "@builder.io/qwik-city/vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig(() => {
    return {
        plugins: [qwikCity(), qwikVite(), tsconfigPaths()],
        base: "/qwik-digency-home/", // <REPO>
        preview: {
            headers: {
                "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=600",
            },
        },
    };
});
```

/adapters/static/vite.config.ts

```
import { staticAdapter } from "@builder.io/qwik-city/adapters/static/vite";
import { extendConfig } from "@builder.io/qwik-city/vite";
import baseConfig from "../../vite.config";

export default extendConfig(baseConfig, () => {
    return {
        build: {
            ssr: true,
            rollupOptions: {
                input: ["@qwik-city-plan"],
            },
        },
        plugins: [
            staticAdapter({
                origin: "https://da8ah.github.io/qwik-digency-home/", // <URL>/<REPO>
            }),
        ],
    };
});
```